# Acquire lock/release lock, solving racing conditions in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any class to acquiring/releasing locks, using different "drivers" for that?
Saying "drivers" I mean different backends for locking: locking with `files`, lockign with `memcache`, locking with `redis`, locking with `shared memory` etc.

Something like...

```
$Locker = new Locker(new FileLockerDriver());
$Locker->aquire($id);
//do something here...
$Locker->release($id);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism like the one you described, but there are multiple lock functionalities: There is [`flock()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) (a file-lock) and [Semaphores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php). There may be more that I do not know of.